# Why Virtual host configuration does not work?

Tags: apache, vhosts, hosts

I want to redirect on my computer request made to domain.com to my wamp server directory mystaticweb.
I've create in my local hosts file the following configuration :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.domain.com
127.0.0.1       domain.com
```

I see that the domain.com and www.domain.com are both redirected to 127.0.0.1 which is by default wamp server.

I need to point domain.com and www.domain.com to the directory mystaticweb ( this directory is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\mystaticweb ). So i create a Vhost configuration in `C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file, i added :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/wamp/www/mystaticweb"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've restarted many times. But when i access to www.domain.com or domain.com from the browser, i've always pointing to 127.0.0.1 and not to the directory mystaticweb. 
I am surely missing something but i don't know really what.

Thanks

Comment: And you included this vhosts file in httpd.conf? like: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: @bksi yes i did not know that extra file conf are not by default include in the conf

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your hosts file is in the wrong format - it should lead off with the IP address and any names are to the right, delimited by whitespace. You can have many on a single line if you want.

Your host file entry should read:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost www.domain.com domain.com

Secondly, the hosts file only  pertains to OUTBOUND requests, simply finding the right host to go to, and so it won't help anyone else who's trying to get to your pages; the right place to put that information is in your domain's "zone file" which is a component of DNS - and that's a whole 'nother topic!

You will need to contact your domain name's registrar for assistance in configuring your two required (and any optional) DNS servers - most registrars provide DNS services for their customers.

After that, your basic virtual host section looks ok, but we don't have enough information on your configuration. For example, what version of apache? Is it under something like Cygwin or free-standing on Windows? Etc.

In my case, I've got an apache installation that uses a conf directory and a sister directory, conf.d. Conf contains the file httpd.conf which contains the configuration and OPTIONALLY MAY, depending on apache version, contain virtual host entries. However, in my case, I have a file called virtualhosts.conf in the conf.d directory which has entries like this:

```
<VirtualHost 67.101.113.5:80>
    ServerName ronstransaxles.com
    ServerAlias www.ronstransaxles.com
    # ServerAdmin webmaster@RonsTransaxles.com
    DocumentRoot /users/www/RonsTransaxles
    ErrorLog /users/www/logs/RonsTransaxles.com-error_log
    CustomLog /users/www/logs/RonsTransaxles.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

There are many versions of apache out there today; you need to be specific so we can help you.